# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'panda' though panda is installed on my mac os

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed anaconda on my mac os. But when I am trying to import panda library, It is throwing error as panda module not found.

So when I again try to install panda. It says panda already installed on machine

```
C27:python-programming jyoti.aditya$ pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in 
/Users/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in 
/Users/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) 
(2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in 
/Users/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) 
(2018.5)
 Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in 
/Users/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) 
(1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in 
/Users/aditya/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python- 
dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)
```

But when I try to import Panda library in my python code. It throws error

```
C27:python-programming aditya$ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 07:39:16)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import panda as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'panda'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module name is `pandas`, not `panda`. Customarily it is imported like this:

```
import pandas as pd
```

See the [10 Minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) page for a quick introduction to the library.

Answer (score 3):

You have installed `pandas` via `pip` but when trying to import it you have missed the s off the end of `pandas`.

`import pandas as pd` will work.